JPA PageRequest Sort by on nested property
I have the below entities defined
public class Rating {

 @Id
 @Column(name = "ROWID")
 private String rowId;

 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(name = "CMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ROWID")
 private CompanyMaster companyMaster;
}


public class CompanyMaster {

 @Column(name = "NAME")
 private String name;

 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "companyMaster")
 private List<MasterDetail> masterDetails;
}


public class MasterDetail {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "CMP_CLASS", referencedColumnName = "CLASS_DESC")
  private CompanyClassLookup companyClassLookup;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "CMP_ID", referencedColumnName = "ROWID")
  private CompanyMaster companyMaster;
 }

Below is where I have the code property is defined
 public class CompanyClassLookup {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "CLASS_CD")
   private String code;

   @Column(name = "CLASS_DESC")
   private String description;
 }

I would like to have sort by code
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page - 1, rpp, Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, companyMaster.masterDetails.companyClassLookup.code"));

Above one is not working as I am getting the below error
illegal attempt to dereference collection [com.service.model.entity.master.Rating(pr).companyMaster(vm).masterDetails] with element property reference [companyClassLookup]

How to achieve sort function on code here, thanks in advance
